# How to return the file name from the Upload_Handler class in jQuery File Uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to access the file name that is being passed to the index file of the jQuery File Uploader.

I have added a function to attempt to pass that information back to the index.php file. 
I added the function below right after the handle_file_upload function in the UploadHandler class.

```
   public function get_filename(){
       $this->handle_file_upload();
   }
```

I was trying to use in the index.php file

```
 $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
 $name = $upload_handler->get_filename();
```

It does not return the file name as hoped. I have tried to retrieve the files name from the $_POST array but not luck there not really able to see what the array consist of or how to display the post array. 
Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

UPDATE:

I have figured out that if I do this:

```
 $fn = $upload_handler->post($files);
```

This returns all the information I need in a array.

It returns the array below

```
           array ('files' => 

              array ( 0 => 

              stdClass::__set_state(

                    array(
                            'name' => 'Intake-2 (1).xls',

                            'size' => 0,       

                            'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',       

                           'error' => 'File upload aborted',       

                       'deleteUrl' => 'http://omp.com/test/documents/?file=Intake-2%20%281%29.xls',       

                      'deleteType' => 'DELETE',

                     )
                   ),

                 ),

              )
```

Need to access the values in this multidimensional array.
Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to assign the results of get_filename to a variable you have to return them: return $this->handle_file_upload();

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to do that. I added the feature to write the $name to a file so I can see what I was getting back and now I can see that I am getting a std:class array back but not the file name that was uploaded. It is returning as a file numbered file. like 1415128278-724